# Packer --debug produces the wrong ssh keypair

Tags: amazon-ec2, ssh, packer

I am trying to run packer with debug, but cannot ssh into my instance. Every attempt causes this error:

```
$ ssh -i ./ec2_amazon-ebs.pem centos@1.2.3.4 -vvvv
ssh_exchange_identification: read: Connection reset by peer
```

I attempted to check this against the packer keypair by generating a new public key with:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f ./ec2_amazon-ebs.pem
```

I then added this in aws as a key pair and then compared the fingerprints.  They are different so packer seems to be either setting the wrong key in aws or giving me the incorrect private key.

Comment: "[GENERAL SSH SUPPORT IS OFF-TOPIC](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ssh/info)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution was to generate another ssh key (`packer-testing-a.pem`) and then set that as the keypair to use:

```
"builders": [
  {
    ....
    "ssh_keypair_name": "packer-testing-a",
    "ssh_private_key_file": "./packer-testing-a.pem",
    ....
  }
]
```

This does defeat the purpose of running debug and creating a local key pair.